# Why does this PySpark join fail?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I misunderstand the performance of PySpark in the following example.

I have several DataFrame's and I join them consequently.

```py
print"users_data"
print users_data.show()
print"calc"
print calc.show()
print"users_cat_data"
print users_cat_data.show()

data1 = calc.join(users_data, ['category_pk','item_pk'], 'leftouter')
print "DATA1"
print data1.show()
data2 = data1.join(users_cat_data, ['category_pk'], 'leftouter')
print "DATA2"
print data2.show()
data3 = data2.join(category_data, ['category_pk'], 'leftouter')
print "DATA3"
print data3.show()
data4 = data3.join(clicks_data, ['category_pk','item_pk'], 'leftouter')
print "DATA4"
print data4.show()

data4.write.parquet(output + '/test.parquet', mode="overwrite")
```

I expect that `leftouter` joining will return the left side DataFrame with matchings (if any) from the right side DataFrame.

Soma sample outputs:

```
users_data
+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
|   category_pk|   item_pk|             unique_users|
+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
|           321|       460|                        1|
|           730|       740|                        2|
|           140|       720|                       10|


users_cat_data
+--------------+-----------------------+
|   category_pk|   unique_users_per_cat|
+--------------+-----------------------+
|           111|                    258|
|           100|                    260|
|           750|                      9|
```

However, I observe a different behaviour. I used `show()` to print out the first 5 rows of all DataFrame's that I use in joining operations. ALL DataFrames contain data. But I get the following error:

```
None
DATA1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest.py", line 884, in <module>
    args.field1, args.field2, args.field3)
  File "mytest.py", line 802, in calc
    print data1.show()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1512391881474_5650/container_1512391881474_5650_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 336, in show
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1512391881474_5650/container_1512391881474_5650_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1512391881474_5650/container_1512391881474_5650_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1512391881474_5650/container_1512391881474_5650_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o802.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at 

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:794)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:793)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:793)
```

I do not understand why I get Task Serialization error at line `print data1.show()`. The DataFrame's used to create `ata1` are not empty. Also, `show()` is successfully used 2 lines above this line of code.

Sometimes it fails at the last line `data4.write.parquet(output + '/test.parquet', mode="overwrite")` and when I delete it, it runs well. But now it fails even earlier on the line `data1.show()`.

How to solve this problem. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Based on your stacktrace - is users_cat_data actually None? And what do the first 2 show() print as?

Comment: @ayplam: No, `users_cat_data` is not empty. There is nothing empty before DATA1. Also, I do not know what `None` refers to. It appears everywhere when I use `show()`, but then `show()` prints out the content. So, I am completely missed.

Comment: @ayplam: I added some sample output for `users_data` and `users_cat_data`. The DataFrame `calc` contains more columns, but it is also printed out without any issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* the reason for the top-most `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult` is that while requesting `BroadcastExchangeExec` physical operator for broadcasting a relation  (aka *table*)  it simply timed out (after the default 5 minutes of waiting until it finishes).

That's the low-level background on the meaning of the exception.

Now, you may be asking yourself, why could that be happening in the first place?

Set `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout` as `-1` to disable the timeout completely (that will cause the thread to wait for the broadcast to finish indefinitely) or increase it to 10 or so minutes.

You could also disable broadcasting a table by setting `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to `-1`.

That however would just work around a more serious issue that happens with your environment.

My *guess* is that your YARN cluster (guessing by `/mnt/yarn/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1512391881474_5650/container_1512391881474_5650_01_000001`) is tight on resources and the network may be sluggish too.

All in all, my *guess* is that some tables in your queries are lower than the default 10MB that causes Spark SQL optimizer to choose broadcasting (over other means of distributing datasets over executors).

I *think* that there's something more serious going on in the cluster and you're facing some temporary problems until...the admins fix the YARN cluster. Could the cluster be under more load when you submitted the PySpark application?

> I do not understand why I get Task Serialization error

I *think* you can simply disregard it as a side effect of the earlier issue(s) given how PySpark works under the covers with two processes (i.e. Python and a JVM) communicating over a socket.

Comment: Than you very much. I am reading your answer. So far I can tell you that I always use the following conf in `spark-submit`: `--conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=1000`.

Comment: `1000` seconds? That's around 15 mins, isn't it? I _suspect_ the network is slow(er) between the driver machine and the executors. Check pings and such.

Comment: Indeed this error happens when the cluster is under more load and I have several parallel Spark jobs running in different queues. Many thanks for your help.